# Does it need a relu function for bert fine tuning?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, fine-tuning

For example, if it is a multi-class classification, is the following line necessary in the forward function?

```
final_layer = self.relu(linear_output)
```

The class definition is below:

```
class BertClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5):

        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 5)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, input_id, mask):

        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids= input_id, attention_mask=mask,return_dict=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        #final_layer = self.relu(linear_output)
        return linear_output
```

Comment: You can use relu just fine, its not necessarily even the original paper stated the use of Gelu gives better result but never really give any reason as to why it performs better

Comment: @EdwinCheong The Gelu was used in pre-training, and in the paper, it didn't say whether  activation (Relu or Gelu) should be used or not. Did you mean in the fine-tuning code above, the 'relu' line can be commented out?

Comment: You can just comment it out but you should add before the linear layer to be exact

Comment: "but you should add before the linear layer to be exact": What do you mean? Where to add relu?

Comment: Questions like yours are usually difficult to answer because they can depend on your downstream task (i.e. try it and you will know the answer). The `relu` function will give you vector representations with plenty of zeros after your fine-tuning which might be less insightful for your downstream task.

Comment: Don't use ReLUs because of the Dead Neuron problem, specially when you use the BERT Embeddings as input for your next model. Information per se can have negative values, so why filter it out with ReLUs? Doesn't make sense. My recommendation is to use GELUs or SELUs or even leaky RELUs for this task. You will see that you will get better results than rather using only RELUs.